# Checking wether a new period needs to be added, and add it if needed

Tags: r, time-series

I work with time series of answers to questions for the homogenized [Business and Consumer survey](https://ec.europa.eu/info/business-economy-euro/indicators-statistics/economic-databases/business-and-consumer-surveys_en) in Sweden. I right now using Eviews to update the series, but would like to be able to do this in R.

In this simplified example I have 3 questions that we have asked started asked on different dates in the past.

```
temp <- c(1:98)
q1 <- ts(temp,start=c(2009,1),frequency = 12)
temp <- c(1:122)
q2 <- ts(temp,start=c(2007,1),frequency = 12)
temp <- c(1:136)
q3 <- ts(temp,start=c(2005,11),frequency = 12)
print(q1)


     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2009   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2010  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
2011  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
2012  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
2013  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
2014  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
2015  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84
2016  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
2017  97  98
```

We update the results in these series twice a month. First we calculate a preliminary result, and later a definitive result. The code updating the series today checks if the period exists in the workfile (Eviews file format), and if not add it. Then it selects (samples) that period (month) and any new values goes to that month.

I want to do this in a similar way.

Say I do a preliminary for March 2017, and the values q1=100, q2=99 and q3=27 should be put into March 2017 for these three series.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066499/how-to-change-a-time-series-value-in-r), but that only updates for a numbered place in the ts-vector, not based on month and not adding a new period.

Comment: `window` seems to successfully extend the time series: `q1 <- window(q1, c(2009, 1), c(2017, 3), extend=TRUE)`.

Comment: While I can do that, and then put in q1 <- replace(q1,99,100) to increase it to 100, I have to check for starting period for each series and how many periods there are in it (to get the 99 correctly) to get be able to put together the code. Seems to be very much work to do something so simple.

Comment: Slightly more automated, there are `start`  and `end` functions you could use: `q1 <- window(q1, start(q1), c(2017, 3), extend=TRUE)`.

Comment: Start(q1) is a good one for that part. But is there a way to check what a specific month has as "order number" (March 2017 have order number 99). Sometimes we must rerun for a previous month.

Comment: In general, you can pull values from vectors with `head` and `tail`. For example `tail(q1, 1)` will give you the final value of q1 and `head(q1, 5)` will give you the first 5 values.

Comment: Yes, but that does not give me that March 2017 is the 99th value in the list for q1 and 123rd in q2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to solve the problem:

```
tsenter <- function(series,year,month,value)
{
  startper <- start(series)
  endper <- end(series)

  if(startper[1]==year)
  {
    periods <-month - startper[2]+1
  }
  else if(startper[1]+1==year)
  {
    periods <- 12-startper[2]+1+month
  }
  else
  {
    periods <- 12-startper[2]+1+month+(year-startper[1]-1)*12
  }
  if(periods>0)
  {
    if(endper[1]<year || (endper[1]==year && endper[2]<month))
    {
      series <- window(series, start(series), c(year, month), extend=TRUE)
    }
    print(periods)
    print(value)
    series <- replace (series,periods,value)
  }else{
    print("period före startperiod")
  }  
}
```

And here is an example:

```
year <- 2015
month <- 3


temp <- c(1:98)
q1 <- ts(temp,start=c(2009,1),frequency = 12)
temp <- c(1:122)
q2 <- ts(temp,start=c(2007,1),frequency = 12)
temp <- c(1:136)
q3 <- ts(temp,start=c(2005,11),frequency = 12)
q1 <- tsenter (series = q1,year = year,month = month,value = 100)
q2 <- tsenter (series = q2,year = year,month = month,value = 99)
q3 <- tsenter (series = q3,year = year,month = month,value = 27)


print(q1)
print(q2)
print(q3)
```